# What's the difference between the two ways to create games against the computer in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2 there are two ways to set up a game against the computer; you can choose "Play versus A.I." on the single player screen or you can start a "Custom game" from the multiplayer screen and add A.I. opponents.

What are the differences between these two ways to create games against the computer? Does one have any advantages over the other?

Comment: i do not own SC2 so i am going out on a limb, but probably Play Versus A.I. is just quicker to access and setup.

Comment: @Xantec: The setup works exactly the same in both cases, just that you don't have the option to add human players when you do it from the single player screen...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Play versus A.I." is a single player mode, you can NOT get achievements, it IS available during offline play.

"Custom game" is a multiple player mode, where you can play against A.I's or humans, or a mix of both. during this mode you CAN get achievements, but you MUST be connected to battle net the whole time.

Comment: Also in Custom Game there's a 10 second timer before the match begins whereas in single player I believe it's either immediate or the normal 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

One important aspect of a custom game is the ability to choose options before the game starts such as map, speed and in particular race. If you want to practice your TvP on Cloud Kingdom vs a hardest AI at fastest speed you can select exactly those conditions. Player vs AI is random map and random opponent.